# SQL server query with multiple (same ID different date and different image) (filter by last date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Sample and result how I want]

I want to fetch data from a huge db that same ID number each yea , but different photo for each date

I want query to filter and show result with Last date including (ID and photo) to the given ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the most efficient method is:

```
select n.*
from nid n
where n.date = (select max(n2.date) from nid n2 where n2.id = n.id);
```

For performance, you want an index on `nid(id, date)`.

Comment: This query work correctly and show last photo added  but I want to make it filter on given ID 

eg ID = A6666 , A9999

Comment: @user12209531 . . . Just add the condition to the outer `where` clause.